# max-width issue in IE11

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to add a left bung in mandatory field in my forms using some bootstrap class.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
     <span class="input-group-addon label-danger" style="max-width:10px;"></span>
     <input id="Name"maxlength="30"/>
</div>
```

This give me the display that I am looking in all browser except IE11. In IE11 the width remains the same as if I didn't add the max-width attribute.
This is the required outcome:

[image]

And this is what I get in IE11 (the width is not the same)

[image]

Comment: are you using an empty element as a left margin?

Comment: Yes it is an empty span

Comment: so may I ask you why don't you simply remove that span and  set a padding-left to the parent div?

Comment: I added screen shot to describe more my problem

Comment: Please add CSS or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oussama_gd/efyg031L/ On firefox I got a thin span with small width but it is not the case on IE11. I noticed that if the width is big like 300px the width of the span changes even in IE11

Comment: http://codepen.io/e-river/pen/EvzLI

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your stylesheet.

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```